# Shifting parameter orders confusion - Recursive Function

Tags: python

Working on Towers of Hanoi - Trying to understand shifting parameter order in a recursive context.

I'm able to trace the stack for the most part, but check out the code below. I don't understanding why the original def (fr, to) order is printed when n-1 is used in the else call, but switches to the new (spare, to) order when 1 is used. Why doesn't it print the (spare, to) order either way?

More generally, first one prints 'move from P1 to P2' but second one prints 'move from P3 to P2' - why?

```
def printMove(fr, to):
    print('move from ' + str(fr) + ' to ' + str(to))

def Towers(n, fr, to, spare):
    if n == 1:
        printMove(fr, to)
    else:        
        Towers(n-1, spare, to, fr)

print(Towers(3, 'P1', 'P2', 'P3'))
                #fr    #to   #spare




def printMove(fr, to):
    print('move from ' + str(fr) + ' to ' + str(to))

def Towers(n, fr, to, spare):
    if n == 1:
        printMove(fr, to)
    else:
        Towers(1, spare, to, fr)

print(Towers(3, 'P1', 'P2', 'P3'))
                #fr    #to   #spare
```

I expected both instances of code to print 'move from P3 to P2' because I thought in both else calls of Towers the (spare, to, fr) order would replace the original def order, but it alternates between the two depending on whether 1 or n-1 is used as the first parameter.

Comment: 20 years ago, I too asked similar question. Based on my experience, I'd like to suggest (1) you play with actual rings (or at least sheets of paper cut in different sizes with numbers on top) -- remember how you moved the rings and (2) trace your program (or run and observe) and see if it is similar to how you move. 

Change your program until the movement matches.

Comment: Because you call the function recursively with the arguments in a different order: `Towers(n-1, spare, to, fr)`

Answer (score 0):

The first part of code would simply switch the poles until you get the original order, which is why you're getting `move from P1 to P2` in the first time.

Executing your second example does print `move from P3 to P2`. This is because, `n != 1` then it replaces the spare and then the `spare` is now the `from` and the `to` remains the same.

This is not a complete part of code for Towers of Hanoi. The [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) would have you print each time a disk moves.

To understand the algorithm, it might take you a while (as it did for me) but I'll try my best:

How would you move `n` disks from the first pole to the second pole using the third pole as an helper? You could look at it like this - If you had a solution to move all but the last (largest) disk to the third pole (in the correct order), then you could move the last disk to the second pole and then move the entire third pole onto the second and you're done. Going by the same idea recursively, we can get the following code:

```py
def printMove(fr, to):
    print('move from ' + str(fr) + ' to ' + str(to))

def Towers(n, fr, to, spare):
    if n == 1:
        printMove(fr, to)
    else:
        Towers(n-1, fr, spare, to)
        printMove(fr, to)        
        Towers(n-1, spare, to, fr)
```

So what we have, if you try to "read it out loud", is this:

1. Move the first `n-1` disks from `fr` to `spare` using the `to` pole
2. Move the largest disk from the `fr` pole onto the `to` pole
3. Move all the original `n-1` disks that we moved from `spare` to `to`

**Note** - You don't need to use `print` when applying the `Towers` function, it doesn't return anything and simply prints as it is.

Comment: I just wanted to use an altered version of the full code to illustrate my question. I understand the algorithm conceptually, and was even able to trace the stack but I always get the prints wrong. I don't understand why these two bits of code would print two different things, given that from what I can tell in both cases printMove is called by a Towers with the same parameters - I feel like this must be where I'm going astray?

Comment: As I wrote - in the first example, you're simply calling the towers function each time with a switch in the 'spare' and 'fr' parameters - Doing 2 switches (One for `n=3` and another for `n=2`) will restore the "original" order of the poles and then print the `move from P1 to P2`. In the second example, you're only switching it once (Then you call the function with `n=1` which will stop switching) and then you get `move from P3 to P2`

Comment: Thanks. It's that oscillation I still don't really understand. I was thinking in the first example the spare / fr switch would simply happen on the first else call and then repeat. Is a (spare, to, fr) call 'switching' the next (spare, to, fr) somehow? I know I'm going to feel super dumb when it finally makes sense to me.

Comment: Well, yes. If you write down the actual order of invocation of functions then it's `1. Towers(3, 'P1', 'P2', 'P3')` which goes to the `else` clause, then `2. Towers(2, 'P3', 'P2', 'P1')`, which also goes to the `else` clause, then `3. Towers(1, 'P1', 'P2', 'P3')`, which goes to the `if` clause which prints `move from P1 to P2`